# urlencode() strings for mailto:subject= with dash characters that can be properly decoded

Tags: php, mailto

I have a string, for example "2013 International Truck – XZ1234" which I need to urlencode()  and include in a mailto subject= in a way that will be properly decoded. I have tested this in the following way:

```
$encodedstring = urlencode("mailto:info@something.com?subject=2013 International Truck – XZ1234")
<a href="<?php $encodedstring ?>">Email Us</a>
```

The link will then look like this:

```
<a href="mailto:info@southlandit.com?subject=2013+International+Truck+%26%238211%3B+XZ1234">Email Us</a>
```

The subject then is decoded and displayed in the subject input field to look like this: (this has been tested in Gmail)

```
2013 International TerraStar Truck &#8211; NT2031
```

Is there an alternative to urlencode() or some other way to encode this string so that all characters, including dashes are properly decoded in mail clients?

Comment: That doesn't seems like something urlencode() would do on its own. Are you 1000000% sure there isn't a `htmlentities()` call in your code somewhere?

Comment: You're right @Pekka웃. I didn't realize the variable I was encoding had `htmlentities()` applied to it first via Wordpress's `the_title()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is being double encoded. `%26%238211%3B` is the encoded form of `&#8211;`, which is the encoded form of the dash. Trace your code execution to see where it is being encoded twice.

Comment: Perfect. That did it! Thanks. I was using a post title in Wordpress using `the_title()` which I needed to change to `html_entity_decode( get_the_title() )`

Answer (score 0):

you can use following to remove special formatting..

```
remove_filter( ‘the_title’ , ‘wptexturize’ );

remove_filter( ‘the_content’ , ‘wptexturize’ );

remove_filter( ‘the_excerpt’ , ‘wptexturize’ );

remove_filter( ‘comment_text’ , ‘wptexturize’ );

remove_filter( ‘list_cats’ , ‘wptexturize’ );
```

[wptexturize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize)